# Nesper engine/C#: issue in internal current time

Tags: c#, esper, nesper

I'm using the Nesper engine (http://www.espertech.com/esper/nesper.php) in C# and I'm facing an issue.

When trying to retrieve the engine's internal time, the date returned seems to be wrong as it is the date as of yesterday.

The code below is a dummy sample that reproduced the problem. 
From what I understand 'engineTime' and 'DateTime.UtcNow' should be equal, but this is not the case.

```
using com.espertech.esper.client;
using System;

namespace NesperDate_bug
{
    class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EPServiceProvider _esperSvc = EPServiceProviderManager.GetProvider("test", new Configuration());

            DateTime engineTime = Nesper2DateTime(_esperSvc.EPRuntime.CurrentTime);

            Console.WriteLine("Esper engine time:\t" + engineTime);
            Console.WriteLine("System utc time:\t" + DateTime.UtcNow);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static DateTime Nesper2DateTime(long millisec)
        {
            return new DateTime(millisec * 10000);
        }
    }
}
```

The result I'm getting in the Console is:

```
Esper engine time:    16/09/2017 10:30:25
System utc time:      17/09/2017 10:30:25
```

Is the problem coming from Nesper, or is my 'Nesper2DateTime' function wrong?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

After looking at Nesper' source code, it appears that my 'Nesper2DateTime' function was wrong. It works when using Nesper's 'DateTimeHelper.UtcFromMillis' function.

The following

```
using com.espertech.esper.compat;
DateTime engineTime = DateTimeHelper.UtcFromMillis(_esperSvc.EPRuntime.CurrentTime);
```

returns the correct date.